# Clojure - placeholder in sql commands

Tags: jdbc, clojure

I want to have an update function. So there are 6 params for this func.

```
(defn update-user-profile [id email slogan title twitter web_site]
  (sql/with-connection
   db
   (sql/do-commands "update users SET email=? slogan=?
                    title=? twitter=? web_site=? WHERE id=?"id,email,slogan...
```

This is what i want. Is it possible or OK in Clojure?

p.s i know there is a `sql/update-values`. But each time i try this, i get an error like `wrong number of arguments(7)` which is i dont understand.

**edit :** i solved my question with idiomatic way. thank you again.

Comment: As I can see from http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_contrib/clojure.contrib.sql/update-values what you need to do in your case is `(sql/update-values :users ["id=?" id] {:email email :slogan slogan :etc etc})`

Comment: this is what i tried before. but after this execution, there was no any update. all was same.

Comment: If you check https://github.com/clojure/clojure-contrib/blob/master/modules/sql/src/main/clojure/clojure/contrib/sql.clj#L79 you'll see that `do-commands` translates its arguments to `.addBatch` calls, and the later accepts only a single string.

Comment: You can also try `(sq/do-prepared "update users SET email=? slogan=?
                    title=? twitter=? web_site=? WHERE id=?" [email slogan title twitter web-site id])` and pay attention to pass arguments in a correct order because in your question id should be the last, but pass it as the first

Comment: (just a comment): a more idiomatic way to pass those params to `update-user-profile` would be in a form of a map (a single argument), which would be destructured as: `(defn update-user-profile [{:keys [id email slogan title twitter web_site]}]`. it would allow a calling code be much cleaner: e.g. `(update-user-profile profile)`, where a `profile` is such a map

Comment: Can you post the sql/update values example that you're getting an error with? You really ought to get that working. Also, please specify which jdbc library (and version) you're using. Thanks!

Comment: @Bill Actually i solved my problem by writing this functions with idiomatic way. {:title title :body body...}. but i have another question. are there any option to return __created post__'s id after function called? gonna update question for details.

Comment: You should ask that as another question.